# XSD XML minOccurs="0"

Tags: xml, xsd, minoccurs

I'm trying to allow no Res_0_CD tag/value with ResCD tag and value. Below is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ListResult>
        <Result>
            <ResCD>7</ResCD>
            <ResCD>3</ResCD>
            <Res_O_CD>41068</Res_O_CD>
        </Result>
    </ListResult>
```

Associated XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

 <xs:element name="ListResult">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Result" type="Result_Set"  maxOccurs="13"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element> 

<xs:simpleType name="ResCD">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Values 1 through 13.</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="1"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="2"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="3"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="4"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="5"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="6"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="7"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="8"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="9"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="10"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="11"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="12"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="13"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType> 

<xs:simpleType name="Res_O_CD">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="([1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])?"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>  

<xs:complexType name="Result_Set">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="ResCD" type="ResCD"/>
        <xs:element name="Res_O_CD" type="Res_O_CD" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="5"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Error: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'ResCD'. One of '{Res_O_CD}' is expected.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the **default occurrence of elements is *one***.
So in your `xs:complexType` named `Result_Set`, you defined an `xs:element` named `ResCD`. So far, so good - but because the default of occurrences is one, a `Res_O_CD` is expected after the first `ResCD` element.

The solution is to add a `maxOccurs` attribute with a value greater than one, for example:

```
<xs:element name="ResCD" type="ResCD" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
```

Or in the whole type:

```
<xs:complexType name="Result_Set">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="ResCD" type="ResCD" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:element name="Res_O_CD" type="Res_O_CD" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="5"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

So after an arbitrary number of `ResCD` elements there can occur 0 to 5 `Res_O_CD` elements.